# Shutting down a channel of a client from Server using grpc-java

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I have a usecase where in server requires to shutdown a channel from a particular client. Is there a way for the server to do that.
When the channel reaches MAX_CONNECTION_AGE server sends GOAWAY with status code NO_ERROR and ASCII debug data "max_age" right. In a similar way, can server send a goaway to shutdown a channel of a client with a custom ASCII debug data whenever required?

Tried Server.shutdown() but it closes all the channels. I want to shutdown particular channel of a particular client.

Comment: I responded to you on Gitter. This is not available today. We'd need to know more about your use-case, especially the part where you need a specific debug data string.